# Rails 3 middleware modify request headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I am working on my first middleware app and it seems like all of the examples deal with modify the response. I need to examine and modify the request headers in particular, delete some offending headers that cause a bug in Rack 1.2.3 to choke. Here's the typical hello world Rack app.

```
my_middleware.rb

class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    [@status, @headers, @response]
  end
end
```

Does anyone have an example that deals with the request headrers and intercepting them before Rack gets hold of it? I need to modify the request headers before it gets to Rack for parsing. I have this setup, thinking that putting it before Rack might do the trick but I am not sure if order of execution is enforced in this manner.

```
application.rb

config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Lock, "MyMiddleware"
```

Answer (score 22):

In your `call` method, you should be able to modify `env`, which is the Rack Environment. Rack prepends `HTTP_` to each header, so the `Accept` header would be accessed via `env['HTTP_ACCEPT']`.

So if you need to delete certain headers, you should be able to do something like `env.delete('HTTP_ACCEPT')`. Then when you do `@app.call(env)`, it will use your modified `env`.

See [the Rack documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html) for more information on the `env` object (see "The Environment").

Comment: Great, I'll give this a try, do you know if my setup intercepts the headers before Rack does or does the order of loading middleware matter at all in terms of execution order.

Comment: I believe Rack will still intercept the request first, but then pass it on to the middleware instead of directly to Rails. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: If that's the case, then it won't work for me. I just dumped the `@app` object class and it shows `Rack::Lock` meaning that Rack has already gotten to it. Argh.

Comment: I was looking at the source of Rack and I can't find any reference in which the headers are prefixed with 'HTTP_'. I must be looking in the wrong place, where can I find it?

Comment: Note that if you're trying to access a header with hyphens (`-`), the hyphens become underscores (`_`) as well. For example, a header called `X-Token` is accessed as follows: `env['HTTP_X_TOKEN']`.