# How to disable IP Spoofing check in Rails 4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spoofing

I'm getting the following error on my Rails 4 application:

> ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::IpSpoofAttackError: IP spoofing attack?! HTTP_CLIENT_IP="xx.xx.xx.xx" HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR="xx.xx.xx.xx"

We don't need this type of security check, so after some Googling around I found this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10780

> When an intermediate proxy inserts the user IP address both in the
> HTTP_CLIENT_IP and the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, and this address is
> private, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp raises an IpSpoofAttackError
> exception.
>
> When an enterprise proxy includes the user's IP address in a header,
> this will commonly be private. Removing private IP addresses from the
> chain contained in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR should probably be done only
> when the address is not an exact match of the one found in
> HTTP_CLIENT_IP. If it is a match, that should be the user's IP
> address.
>
> This happens for example with the following environment:
>
> HTTP_CLIENT_IP: 172.17.19.51 HTTP_X_BLUECOAT_VIA: ffffffffffffffff
> HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 172.17.19.51 REMOTE_ADDR: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (this
> would be a public IP address)

---

A fix presented here:

> As a work-around, I've disabled this check in config/application.rb:
>
> config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false

However this doens't seem to work in Rails 4. What is the new call and how do I set it site wide?

Answer (score 16):

Rather than turning off the warning, it might be better to fix the actual problem. Here's my rephrasing of what Rails is telling you:

> This request seems to have come through two different reverse proxies. One of them set the `CLIENT_IP` header to the user's IP address; the other set the `X_FORWARDED_FOR` header. One of those values is probably correct, the other probably contains the IP of a reverse proxy, and I have no way to tell which is which. I can't reliably determine this user's IP address, so I'm going to reject the request.

The "correct" solution is to stop setting both headers. For that you'll need to track down where they're coming from (I'd start with your Bluecoat device) and find out if they're both needed. Usually you'll only use one or the other.

If it turns out they are both needed (I've seen stranger things), then you'll need to find out which header is being set first (assuming there are two proxies in the chain). Then you can write a custom middleware that deletes the other HTTP header.

See [Rails 3 middleware modify request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959798/rails-3-middleware-modify-request-headers) for pointers on how to create your own middleware. Insert it before the RemoteIp middleware, clear out whichever header has the "bad" value, and you should be good.

Comment: Below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71848808/470512 is a good code snippet for Rails. Example from a US network, HTTP_CLIENT_IP set to Comcast cable IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR set by a cloud security gateway such as Forcepoint. In this case, it looks like X-Forwarded-For should be removed because it points to the proxy, not the client.

Answer (score 5):

`config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check` *should* work based on the [calling chain](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/f6797a7683e5367046217fa85900f0288a504f84/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb) for [RemoteIp](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb).

You should be able to achieve the same effect by setting `config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies` to a [regex matching all IPv4 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address).

Answer (score 2):

`config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false` is still the correct setting.

However, [`web-console`](https://github.com/rails/web-console) (included in Rails `development` environment by default since Rails 4.2) doesn't respect this setting and raises `IpSpoofAttackError` whenever it's included in the application stack, even when `spoofing_check` is `false`. A workaround for this issue is to remove `web-console` from your environment's application stack.

See [rails/rails#32379](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32379) and [rails/web-console#254](https://github.com/rails/web-console/pull/254) for more details on this issue and a proposed fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which of X-Forwarded-For or Client-Ip you want, you can delete the other one in a rack middleware (here for nginx):

```
# the Client-Ip header can come from misconfigured remote proxies.  Filter it out
# since we know nginx always uses X-Forwarded-For to avoid IpSpoofAttackError.
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, Rack::Config do |env|
  env.delete 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that `config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false` still works (Rails 7).